# How to disable chromium focus to new tab when clicking link?

Tags: chromium

At chromium 56 when a link at an `html` document is clicked focus is gained at new `window`.

Related:

- [How do i stop Chrome from automatically switching tabs?](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/ewUKQObBqEc). The option "Disable Focus existing tab on open." is not present at `chrome:flags` at chromium 56.
- [How can I force Chrome to open new tabs via middle-click/command+click/ctrl+click without focusing on them?](https://superuser.com/questions/1103564/how-can-i-force-chrome-to-open-new-tabs-via-middle-click-commandclick-ctrlclic)

How to disable focus at newly opened tab and retain focus at current tab?

Comment: Can you give an example of a link that **doesn't** open as a background tab when you control+click it?

Comment: @DKBose When right-click on a link and click "Open link in new tab" the expected result is for new tab to open loading resource in background,  though for current `window` in tab to retain focus. Currently, the new tab gains focus, whether `ctrl` is simultaneously pressed or not.

Comment: What happens when you use the scroll wheel to open a new tab, is it opened in the background or is the new tab given focus? This may not be ideal, but have you tested this functionality in a different Desktop Environment or possibly in a Virtual Machine and seen if the undesired functionality still persists?

Comment: @i_pk_pjers_i What do you mean by "scroll wheel"?

Comment: By scroll wheel I meant the scroll wheel button on your mouse - that is supposed to open a new tab in the background when you click on a link.

Comment: Currently using touchpad. The issue does not occur at firefox 52, where new tab is opened while current tab retains focus

Comment: I recommend that you [edit] pertinent details into your post about your configuration from [our chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57657/discussion-between-elder-geek-and-guest271314) as between us we've covered every base I can think of and I cannot reproduce the [bug you reported](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=714785&can=2&q=--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified) I can however confirm that my answer works fine for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was caused by [`--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs`](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#auto-open-devtools-for-tabs) flag being set.

[chrome_switches.cc](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/common/chrome_switches.cc?q=kAutoOpenDevToolsForTabs&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=82)

```
// This flag makes Chrome auto-open DevTools window for each tab. It is
// intended to be used by developers and automation to not require user
// interaction for opening DevTools.
const char kAutoOpenDevToolsForTabs[]       = "auto-open-devtools-for-tabs";
```

Removing the flag from launcher resolved issue. [Bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=714785&can=2&q=--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified).

Comment: Thats odd, I can't reproduce this unconfirmed bug.

Comment: @ElderGeek What steps did you take to reproduce?

Comment: Only the steps necesarry to substantiate it. `chromium-browser  --auto-open-devtools-for-tabs`

Comment: @ElderGeek If you launch chromium from `terminal` while an instance of chromium is open the new instance will have same settings as open instance. Try specifying a different `--user-data-dir`than open instance of chromium, which does not have to exist when command is run,  `chromium-browser --user-data-dir="/home/USER/.config/chromium-tab-focus-test" --auto-open-devtools-for-tabs`. You can then delete the created directory following test `rm -rf /home/USER/.config/chromium-tab-focus-test`

Comment: @ElderGeek Alternatively, close all open instances of chromium, modify desktop launcher, then click desktop launcher to open new instance of chromium with `--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs` flag set.

Comment: I didn't have another instance of chromium running. If I do that it reports that there's another instance running and opens a tab in the existing instance via the terminal. I'm sorry If I was unclear. I stand by my previous comment.

Comment: @ElderGeek All instances of chromium should be closed to perform test. Or, specify a different `--user-data-dir`.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/904782/how-to-disable-chromium-focus-to-new-tab-when-clicking-link/908510?noredirect=1#comment1427804_908510

Comment: @ElderGeek Did you launch with a different `--user-data-dir` set?  What do you mean by _"I stand by my previous comment"_ Which previous comment?  _"I didn't have another instance of chromium running. If I do that it reports that there's another instance running and opens a tab in the existing instance via the terminal."_ Do not gather what you are trying to convey?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57657/discussion-between-elder-geek-and-guest271314).

Answer (score 0):

**A Fresh install of Chromium Version 57.0.2987.98**  installed from the repositories provides the behavior you desire. "right-click on a link and click "Open link in new tab" the new tab opens loading resource in background.It's available via the software center as seen below:

[image: Chromium57]

As you can see, I don't experience this issue with a clean install and no extensions enabled:

[image: extensions].

**EDIT:** If you are still experiencing this difficulty it's likely due to [one of the plugins](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/tabs%20to%20the%20front?hl=en) that provide this behavior that you may have forgotten that you installed. OR you are launching [chromium with a flag set](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags)  which you didn't mention in your question that is causing this problem for you.

**Further edit:** Launching with only `--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs` flag set does not cause this behavior. It seems that this problem only occurs when launching with both `--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs` flag and `--user-data-dir` set.
Sources:

Testing.on 64 bit Xenial 16.04 LTS (Unity) & Xubuntu 16.04 32-bit (XFCE)

[How to disable chromium focus to new tab when clicking link?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904782/how-to-disable-chromium-focus-to-new-tab-when-clicking-link/908478?noredirect=1#comment1427708_908478)

Comment: No, that does not solve issue. Current version of chromium is actually `57.0.2987.98`

Comment: You'll note that yes, that is the version I have installed. Edited answer

Comment: That is the version of chromium am currently using. The behaviour described at Question persists at the same version.

Comment: Read the edit to my answer

Comment: No extensions are installed.

Comment: I suggest that you double check that statement. :-)

Comment: "Boo… You have no extensions :-( ". According to `navigator.plugins` the only plugin  installed is `Chromium PDF Viewer`

Comment: Just found the possible issue. Launched a different instance of chromium without `--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs` flag set, where when right-click on hyperlink the new tab is opened in background, while retaining focus at current tab. Appears to be a bug associated with that flag.

Comment: I'm glad you got it sorted. :-)

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=714785&can=2&q=--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified